# How to merge four tables in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have four tables: `predicted_tags`, `actual_tags`, `tags_names` and `news_text`.

In tables `predicted_tags` and `actual_tags` rows names are tags id. In these tables `1` means True  and `0` means False.

Shape of `predicted_tags` and `actual_tags` is (23413, 1369).

`predicted_tags`:

```
print(predicted_tags)
+-------+-----+---+-----+------+------+
|       |   1 | 3 | ... | 8345 | 8347 |
+-------+-----+---+-----+------+------+
| 35615 |   0 | 0 | ... |    1 |    0 |
| 58666 |   1 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |
| 16197 |   0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    1 |
| 68824 |   0 | 0 | ... |    1 |    1 |
| 22277 |   0 | 0 | ... |    1 |    0 |
+-------+-----+---+-----+------+------+
```

`actual_tags`:

```
print(actual_tags)
+-------+-----+---+-----+------+------+
|       |   1 | 3 | ... | 8345 | 8347 |
+-------+-----+---+-----+------+------+
| 35615 |   0 | 0 | ... |    1 |    0 |
| 58666 |   1 | 1 | ... |    0 |    0 |
| 16197 |   0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    1 |
| 68824 |   0 | 0 | ... |    1 |    1 |
| 22277 |   0 | 1 | ... |    1 |    0 |
+-------+-----+---+-----+------+------+
```

`tags_names`:

```
print(tags_names)
+--------+----------+-------------+
|        |   tag_id |  tag_name   |
+--------+----------+-------------+
| 127579 |        1 | politics    |
| 108814 |        3 | economics   |
|    ... |      ... | ...         |
|     18 |     8345 | hot         |
| 257141 |     8347 | environment |
+--------+----------+-------------+
```

`news_text`:

```
print(news_text)
+----------+------------------------+-----------------------------+
|          |       news_name        |         news_content        |
+----------+------------------------+-----------------------------+
|    35615 | Secret of…             |  Hi! Today I will talk...   |
|    58666 | Conversations with a … |  I have a big experience... |
|    16197 | Harm of alcohol        |  Today, we…                 |
|      ... | ...                    |  ...                        |
|    68824 | Hot news               |  Celebrity with...          |
|    22277 | Finance market         |  Last week…                 |
+----------+------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I want to get the next table:

```
+-------+------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
|       |       news_name        |        news_content        |     predicted_tags     |        actual_tags        |
+-------+------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
| 35615 | Secret of…             | Hi! Today I will talk...   | ['hot']                | ['hot']                   |
| 58666 | Conversations with a … | I have a big experience... | ['politics']           | ['politics', 'economics'] |
| 16197 | Harm of alcohol        | Today, we…                 | ['environment']        | ['environment']           |
| 68824 | Hot news               | Celebrity with...          | ['hot', 'environment'] | ['hot', 'environment']    |
| 22277 | Finance market         | Last week…                 | ['hot']                | ['hot', 'economics']      |
+-------+------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
```

How can I do this using Pandas?

Comment: This is a task you have, not a question. What have you tried so far? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question.

Comment: I don't know how convert `1` list of tags names and merge it with table `news_text`

Comment: what is the size of the data ? we can write lambda to get them converted

Comment: Sorry that I did not indicate this in question. I will update my question. Data size is 20K rows in `predicted_tags` / `actual_tags`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `tags_names` df into dictionary and use it to rename columns:

```
tag_names = dict(zip(tags_names['tag_id'], tags_names['tag_names']))

predicted_tags.rename(columns = tag_names, inplace = True)
actual_tags.rename(columns = tag_names, inplace = True)
```

Get the column names where value is 1.

```
news_text['actual_tags'] = (actual_tags == 1 ).apply(lambda y: actual_tags.columns[y.tolist()].tolist(), axis=1)
news_text['predicted_tags'] = (predicted_tags == 1 ).apply(lambda y: predicted_tags.columns[y.tolist()].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, create a column which holds all the actual/predicted values, such as:

```
predicted_tags['pred_loc'] = predicted_tags.values.tolist()
actual_tags['actual_loc'] = actual_tags.values.tolist()
```

Also, if your tag_id (in `tag_names dataFrame`) is in the same order as the columns in your actual and predicted tags dataFrame. Then, just create a list of tags names like

```
tags = tag_names.tag_name.values.tolist()
```

Now, before we convert, we will merge this to the `news_text dataFrame`,

```
news_text = news_text.merge(predicted_tags['pred_loc'], how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
news_text = news_text.merge(actual_tags['actual_loc'], how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Now, we convert:

```
news_text.pred_loc = news_text.pred_loc.apply(lambda x: [tags[i] for i, j in enumerate(x) if j == 1])
news_text.actual_loc = news_text.actual_loc.apply(lambda x: [tags[i] for i, j in enumerate(x) if j == 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert one hot encoding of tags to list of tags by using [pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). I would modify tag_names from dataframe to a series (whose index is tag_id and value is tag name). I'm demonstrating this with only two tags for now.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
            1: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            3: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]}, 
        index=[35615, 58666, 16197, 68824, 22277] ) # predicted_tags
>>> df
       1  3
35615  0  0
58666  1  1
16197  0  0
68824  0  0
22277  0  1
>>> tag_names = pd.DataFrame({"tag_id": [1,3,], 
        "tag_name": ["politics", "economics"]},
         index=[127579, 108814])
>>> tag_names
        tag_id   tag_name
127579       1   politics
108814       3  economics
>>> tags = tag_names.set_index("tag_id").tag_name
>>> tags
tag_id
1     politics
3    economics
Name: tag_name, dtype: object
>>> df.apply( lambda row: [tags.loc[k] for k,v in row.items() if v > 0] , axis=1)
35615                       []
58666    [politics, economics]
16197                       []
68824                       []
22277              [economics]
dtype: object
>>>
```

You should be now able to join this with `news_text` on index.